# In Pig, finding complement of entries in a table

Tags: database, apache-pig

I have a table `A` which contains a list, a table `B` which contains a sub-list of the items in `A`. How should get a table `C` which contains a list which is the complement of `B` in `A`?

I know how to do it in sql. Am not sure how to approach it in Pig.

Thanks.

Comment: could you give us an example to take a look at your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PIG words, you have two "bags" A and B, where B is a subset of A.

If B only contains values in A, you can do C = DIFF(A,B).
However, consider that DIFF removes duplicates, so you will get the complement of B in A reduced to unique values.

Generally, DIFF provides the union of both the complement of B in A and that of A in B.

Comment: Another way: Store in C the outer JOIN of A and B. The nulls in C (in the column from B) indicate which entries are not in B!

Comment: I then misunderstood your case: Joining A and B here means that your two tables were loaded separately, using two different LOAD statements. I thought they were two contiguous bags. My bad.

Comment: No. That's fine. We could use co-grouping to get them into the same table. Your suggestion above is ok!